# How to block actions for branches other than those enabled in yml?

Tags: github-actions

I'm creating some specific branches like for example:

```
- main
- develop
```

And other generics such as:

```
- release/*
- hotfix/*
```

But if there is any name other than these branches, I would like the push to be blocked, is it possible?

The test I did was, create a different branch from these, however, it continues to run push and PR.

**MY CODE:**

```
on:
  push:
  pull_request:
    branches: 
      - main
      - develop
      - release/*
      - hotfix/*
```

Comment: Actions have nothing to do with what you're allowed to push. The only thing your YAML does is to only run that workflow on branches that match the pattern. If you want to enforce a branch naming policy, you could create a workflow that runs on all branch names, but fails if the branch name does not follow your convention.

Comment: @rethab How can I implement this in a matter of code?

Comment: Hi @THIAGO DE BONIS, for `pull_request` events, you could do something like `if: github.head_ref.startsWith(...`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to specify those branches for push also:

```yaml
on:
  push:
    branches: 
      - main
      - develop
      - release/*
      - hotfix/*
  pull_request:
    branches: 
      - main
      - develop
      - release/*
      - hotfix/*
```

Comment: Isn't it the same thing I did above?

Comment: I don't think so. You didn't specify any branches for push and therefore this workflow is triggered on push to any branch

Comment: You can try to convert yaml to json for better perspective - https://www.convertjson.com/yaml-to-json.htm